# Using Three20 to show local images

Tags: iphone, three20

Using Three20's Photo Viewer, how do I display local images?

My images are in my app dir and not in my bundle. Setting the URL to `file://localhost/<escaped path>`gets a successful connection but is not able to download the image because it is expecting a `NSHTTPURLResponse`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three20 use special url schemes for handling in-app resources :

- `bundle://` : app bundle resources (== `mainBundle` == `.app` folder)
- `documents://` : user documents

These schemes are defined at a low level in the library, that means you can use from any `three20` components, tables, buttons... styles and so on the same way you would use external urls.

Comment: I tried documents:// with full path but it accepts a relative path only.

Comment: Look at three20 source code so see how that works. Adding your own scheme is not hard if you need it...

Answer (score -1):

I don't normally work with the `Three20` framework, but I'll give it a go seeing as there's no other answers yet:

If it's expecting an `NSHTTPURLResponse`, you're probably supposed to load the images from a server or you utilized a tutorial that dealt with loading images from a server instead of loading them from the local disk. I've also never in my time developing for iOS seen a file in the filesystem pointed to using `file://`.